# Right align rotated axis title in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

How do I right-align the Y-axis title ("Species") with the axis labels (the three species names), such that the axis title is close to the gray panel? `hjust` does not seem to affect the position.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(iris,
       aes(x = Species,
           y = Sepal.Width)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  labs(x = "Species",
      y = "Sepal Width") +
  coord_flip() +
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(angle = 0, hjust = 0))
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `geom_text` together with `clip = "off"` inside `coord_flip()` which will allow drawing plot element outside of the plot panel. Obviously you will have to play around with `x` and `y` to get the desired output with this manual method

```r
library(ggplot2)

p <- ggplot(iris,
       aes(x = Species,
           y = Sepal.Width)) +
  geom_boxplot() +
  labs(x = NULL,
       y = "Sepal Width") +
  coord_flip(clip = "off") + # add clip = off here
  theme(axis.title.y = element_text(angle = 0, hjust = 0))

p +
  # add axis title here
  geom_text(
    x = 3.5,
    y = 1.85,
    inherit.aes = FALSE,
    label = "Species",
    check_overlap = TRUE,
    hjust = 1,
    fontface = 'bold',
    size = 5
  ) +
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(1, 1, 1, 2), "lines"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2018-10-27 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Comment: I can't reproduce this plot with ggplot2 version 3.0.0 - the "Species" label is missing.

Comment: Yep works with update. Unexpectedly large difference for an recent and "minor" update...